# HighCharts yAxis too much space around big numbers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[My current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0rA2.png)

Just started using HighCharts. I'm charting a stock price that fluctautes around $1,598 and $1,601 that fluctuates over the course of a day. The changes are all obviously small - but the price is changing - it should not be a straight line. HighCharts seems to just zoom too far out. I've added the `startOnTick: false` etc. with no luck so far. Is there anything obvious I might be missing?

Options below:

```
const options = {
    chart: {
        height: '150px',
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.white02
        margin: 0,
        spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        type: 'datetime',
        gridLineWidth: 1,
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        startOnTick: false,
        minPadding: 10,
        maxPadding: 0
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: 'areaspline',
            data: data[0].data,
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `min` option for the y-Axis to a number just below your minimum - in your case perhaps 1595, and have `startOnTick to false` as you've mentioned, that will essentially 'zoom in' on the graph right away for your desired range given the inputs are within that range.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If I set the min manually, it does work - I was hoping that I wouldn't need to specify that, but thats trivial so its what I'll do - thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set min value of yAxis.

```
const options = {
chart: {
    height: '150px',
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.white02
    margin: 0,
    spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
},
xAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    type: 'datetime',
    gridLineWidth: 1,
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    startOnTick: false,
    minPadding: 10,
    maxPadding: 0,
    min: 1550
},
title: {
    text: null
},
legend: {
    enabled: false
},
series: [
    {
        type: 'areaspline',
        data: data[0].data,
    }
  ]
 };
```

options.yAxis.min=1550;

or you can assign minimal value from response array.

Comment: thanks for answer Sameer!! I would vote for yours too if I could (I selected the other answer as it was a couple min earlier)

Comment: No problem. I was writing that time :)